# using fstab to mount network drive with cifs

Tags: server, permissions, samba, fstab, cifs

I'm trying to set up samba on an ubuntu server, and create automatic backups on my ubuntu desktop, both 18.04, but I can't seem to configure fstab properly.

I have ownership of both the server's samba directory and my local mounting point.

Here is the output of `ls -ld /srv/samba/tim` on the server:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 tim tim 4096 Sep 28 02:06 /srv/samba/tim/
```

and the output of `ls -ld /media/ubuntu_server` on the desktop:

```
drwxr-xr-- 2 tim tim 4096 Sep 27 20:20 /media/ubuntu_server/
```

and my attempt at configuring the mount in fstab:

```
//10.0.0.3/tim  /media/ubuntu_server  cifs  vers=1.0,user=tim,noauto,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

For whatever reason, when I boot, or run `sudo mount -a` the directory appears in nautilus, but clicking on it gives me the error `mount: /media/ubuntu_server: operation permitted for root only.`

Yet, if I run `sudo mount /media/ubuntu_server` it prompts for the password for the correct user (tim) and mounts so that I can use it the way I intended.

Could this be an issue with the users permissions?

I really have no idea, so please throw your recomendations at me

Comment: @Terrance `/media` is owned by root:root, is it not enough to own the subdirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by removing the `noauto` option and specifying `uid=1000`

I'm not certain why this combination worked, but trying one or the other was unsuccessful. Hopefully this can help someone else in the future

Answer (score 0):

You're currently mounting a directory for a user that needs root permissions to access that could be causing the permission error. I'd recommend to change the mount directory to somewhere inside your home directory `/home/tim/ubuntu_server`

You can also tweak the fstab file similar to mine.

```
//192.168.1.1/tim /home/tim/ubuntu_server cifs guest,uid=1000,noauto,user,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm 0 0
```

Comment: just for the sake of organization I'd like to keep all devices in `/media`, would it be dangerous to change the permissions on that directory instead?

Comment: Although trivial yes it could be. Just `sudo chown -R tim:tim /media/ubuntu_server` if you want.

Comment: I meant the parent directory, since I already own `/media/ubuntu_server`. can you think of any issues off hand, so I can avoid them in the future? if not, I really appreciate your help this far

Comment: You should be golden as fstab already handles the permissions on the /media/ubuntu_server directory as 0777. You can still set permissions on directories inside that.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Comment: sorry, I think I lost you. you are saying to take ownership of `/media`, correct?

Comment: even after taking ownership of both `/media` and `/media/ubuntu_server` I still get the same "operation permitted for root only" when trying to click on the network drive

Comment: No, you should keep /media permissions for root only, only change permissions on ubuntu_server.